# React DnD - How to get ID of dragged item

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

How can I console log in my file where I have the drop area, the id of the node that I am moving (draggable item). I believe I am supposed to use  `monitor.getItem()`, as specified in the [documentation](http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/drag-source-monitor), but I don't understand it,

I have a `ref={drag}` on my dragable and `ref={drop}` on my droppable node.

**Draggable item:**

```js
  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    item: { type: 'TODO_ITEM' },
    collect: monitor => ({
      isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging()
    }),
    drag: () => {
      console.log('dragging')
    }
  })
```

**Drop area**

```js
  const [{ isOver, canDrop }, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: 'TODO_ITEM',
    collect: mon => ({
      isOver: !!mon.isOver(),
      canDrop: !!mon.canDrop()
    }),
    drop: monitor => {
      console.log(monitor)
      // monitor only returns { type: 'TODO_ITEM' }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it by pulling in the item via props on the dragable item, attaching it to the monitor, and picking it up on the droppable area.

**Draggable item**

```js
export default function TodoItem ({ item }) {

  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    item: { type: 'TODO_ITEM', itemID: item._id },
    collect: monitor => ({
      item: monitor.getItem(),
      isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging()
    })
  })

...
```

Drop area:

```
  const [{ isOver, canDrop }, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: 'TODO_ITEM',
    collect: mon => ({
      isOver: !!mon.isOver(),
      canDrop: !!mon.canDrop()
    }),
    drop: monitor => {
      console.log('moving item:', monitor.itemID)
    }
  })
```

Comment: Update to this answer: The Draggable item now needs to be
`type: 'TODO_ITEM', item: {item._id},...`